# Is it possible to combine more formulas to import data from one google sheet following more than one variable?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS8ir.png)hope that someone can help me with this.

i need to copy specific data from one sheet, based on some rules. I'll try to be as clear as possible, here are the details:

From the sheet "transfers" Copy to the current sheet the info from the cell in column D if the checkbox in column B is checked "true",  but also the info from column G if the checkbox in column E is checked, and also the info from column J if column H is checked.
Hope it's clear.
At the same time I'd also like to add the possibility to write the name of who paid the rent, in the next cell: so in a designated cell write X if you insert data from column D, write Y if you insert data from column G, write Z if you insert data from column J.

Attached are pictures of the table.
[table to get data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRemd.png) -
[outcome idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzmiD.png)

I'm not an expert, so doing some research, I tried many formulas. "ImportRange" and others gave error.

The one that worked well is this one: =filter(transfers!D:D; transfers!B:B=VERO)
giving the exact data and importing all the updated info.
But it works only for one variable, I don't know how to combine to add the other two variables to copy the data from the other column as well.
And of course I don't know how to add the X, Y or Z in the next cell automatically with the data.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Regarding: `Attached is a picture.`  Can find no attached picture.  Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your post.

Comment: @Codedabbler I edit the post. Now you should be able to see the picture. Thank you

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show us what is your expected output for the Copy Sheet you mentioned?

Comment: @CenturyTuna sure. The outcome it's actually quite simple. Just the list of the amoutns paid, all in the same column.  I added the image in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation:

Instead of Google Sheets formula, I created a script for you that when you ticked the checkbox it will copy the value from the respected column related to that checkbox and insert the name beside that value.

To use this code, on your Google Sheets, click Extensions > Appscript. Then copy and paste the code below then save:

[image]

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transfers'); 
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy'); 
  var range = e.range; 
  var row = e.range.getRow(); 
  var column = e.range.getColumn(); 

  if(row >= 4 && column == 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'Copy'){
    
    if(range.getValue() == true){
      var name = sourceSheet.getRange(2,2,1,1).getValue();
      var value = sourceSheet.getRange(row,4,1,1).getValues(); 
      var arr = [[name,value]]; 
      destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,3,1,2).setValues(arr); 
       

    } 
  }

  if(row >= 4 && column == 5 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'Copy'){
    if(range.getValue() == true){
      var name = sourceSheet.getRange(2,5,1,1).getValue();
      var value = sourceSheet.getRange(row,7,1,1).getValue(); 
      var arr = [[name,value]]; 
      destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,3,1,2).setValues(arr); 
    } 
}

if(row >= 5 && column == 8 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'Copy'){
    if(range.getValue() == true){
      var name = sourceSheet.getRange(2,8,1,1).getValue();
      var value = sourceSheet.getRange(row,10,1,1).getValue(); 
      var arr = [[name,value]]; 
      destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,3,1,2).setValues(arr); 
    } 
}
}
```

Click `Run` then a pop-up `Authorization Required` > click `Review permission`.

[image]

Untitled Project wants to access your Google account > click `Allow`.

[image]

Go back to Sheets and make changes on your sheets for the script to work.

### Sample Output:

[image]

### References:

- [if statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)
- [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Hi @serenity , Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to run the script following your instruction but after saving it, when i try to run it it appears a message that says I have no authorization.  I can't understand hot to fix this problem.  Do you have any tips?
Sorry if it's a "dumb" question, this is not my expertise...

Comment: Hello @Bianca G., after you save it, since it is your first time running the script, there should be a pop-up `Authorization Required` > click `Review permission` > <Untitled project> wants to access your Google account > click `Allow`. After you allow it will run the script ignore the error in the execution logs as onEdit() function shouldn't be run instead it works when you made edit in the shift itself, after allowing the permission just go back to your sheets and tick the checkbox so you can test it.

Comment: @Bianca G. I have updated my answer above so you can see the picture as reference to the steps I mentioned since we can't add pictures in the comment section. Let me know if this works or if there are some clarifications needed so that I can further help you.